# Is there a way to set Visual Studio include directories from within your code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I am currently working on a Visual Studio extension that allows the user to easily set up compiler options and such from a simple GUI. While a lot of it works fine, there is one thing that I haven't been able to find a solution for.

I've been asked to make it so that you can set up project configuration properties (for example include directories) from within the addon as well, though I've found nothing for this in the Visual Studio documentation. Is it possible to set the include directories and other configuration properties in C# code or will I have to solve it in another way?

Comment: See following webpage cor command line options : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.  Each project/class should have a .dll file which is a library.  So use the t:/library option.

Comment: See two last articles of section "Articles about build configurations / platforms" at http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/. Maybe the properties are read-write.